# Cannot call method 'destroy' of null when trying to remove item from local storage sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Cannot call method 'destroy' of null ,this is my controller button tap function

```
onRemoveItemButtonTap: function(button, index, target, record){
var code = this.getValues().CODE,
    cartStore = Ext.getStore('CartStore'),
        myItem = cartStore.findRecord('CODE', code);
cartStore.remove(myItem);
cartStore.sync();
```

I tried with cartStore.destroy(myItem) still raising the same error. I have seen some solutions in stack overflow but cant understand how they applicable to my issue.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check to make sure myItem is defined?

Comment: yes, I used to work fine before. suddenly it stopped working and raising that error.

Comment: yeah .It is using localstorage.The items are not removing from the localstorage.

Comment: Try to log the myItem and see if that contains any value.. Looks like it is null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and testing I found the following answer add load() and then sync()

I added autoload to my store but it is not working when I tried to remove record.so I am loading it again and then it is working fine

```
    onRemoveItemButtonTap: function(button, index, target, record){
    var code = this.getValues().CODE,
       cartStore = Ext.getStore('CartStore');
        cartStore.load();
        myItem = cartStore.findRecord('CODE', code);

        cartStore.remove(myItem);
        cartStore.sync();
```